# Is it possible to recharge a respawn anchor automatically?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to make a time bomb for a mini game map, involving a pillar of quartz, and a respawn anchor on the top. Gradually, the respawn anchor recharges, and once it has been fully charged (because you’re in the overworld) it explodes.

The issue is that I need to automatically recharge the anchor to a *full* charge, and then blow it up, without any player involvement.

---

Is there a way to *fully* recharge a respawn anchor automatically and then blow it up without player involvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a little digging around with the `/setblock` command, you can actually set how many charges a respawn anchor has by using the `blockstate` option like so:

*no charges:*
`/setblock ~~~ respawn_anchor 0`

*1 charge:*
`/setblock ~~~ respawn_anchor 1`

*2 charges:*
`/setblock ~~~ respawn_anchor 2`

*3 charges:*
`/setblock ~~~ respawn_anchor 3`

*4 charges:*
`/setblock ~~~ respawn_anchor 4`

*For my problem, I can then clear the respawn anchor, then summon tnt at it’s position, simulating an explosion!*

Answer (score 1):

Use a dispenser!

---

What you need:

- Redstone dust.
- Observers.
- A dispenser.
- Stacks of glowstone.
- A respawn anchor.
- A redstone repeater.

[image: Screenshot of my hotbar.]

###### Layout

Place an observer with 3 pieces of redstone dust coming out of it in an wrap around shape. Next, place another observer to where it's observing this restone trail. Then create a trail to the adjacent face of the tile the last trail stopped at. Go back to the corner of that trail and place a redstone repeater (maximum delay) just after the turn. Then next to the origin, place a dispenser, facing the tile the first observer is watching, at the end of the chains of restone dust:

[image: Screenshot of the repeating configuration.]

###### Fill the Dispenser

Next, place your stacks of glowstone in the dispenser:

[image: Screenshot of the dispenser filled with glowstone.]

###### Place the Anchor

The last step is to place the anchor. This *must* happen last so that it triggers the observer; the completed configuration should look like this:

[image: Screenshot of the completed configuration.]

###### The Problem

There's a big problem with this plan though. Since the respawn anchor explodes in the overworld, you only get one use:

[image: Screenshot of the aftermath.]

Comment: Unfortunately, the system only charged the anchor once (25%) and did not charge fully. I tried putting a bit of delay in the circuit, but with no improvement…

Comment: Also: my apologies. What I meant by “automatically recharge the anchor, and then blow it up”, was that the player does not need to take any action to blow up the anchor. The anchor blows itself up. I’ll be editing my question to include these details.

Comment: @DisplayNameNotFound Sounds fair; I'll leave this answer for future readers. I also updated it to include chaining to achieve a *full* charge, but it still requires user interaction for the explosion.